# Heroku Toolbelt switch between multiple account

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I would like to know what's the best way to switch between heroku account using the heroku toolbelt.

I'm used to have a personnal heroku account which is a collaborator of all of my professionnal heroku app. The problem is when I want to make some changes that have a financial impact : adding / removing addon for example, I cannot do it as a collaborator.
Before heroku toolbelt I was used to change the content of the file `~/.heroku/credentials` but it does not exists anymore with the toolbelt.

Answer (score 32):

Have you tried the heroku accounts [plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts)?

Comment: After installing it, Toolbelt gives me this: `WARNING: deprecated ddollar/heroku-accounts plugin is installed.`

Comment: ah, this comment is two years old, heroku might have a different solution for multiple accounts already

Comment: Heroku now supports this functionality with an official fork of this plugin https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts

Comment: This shouldn't be a plugin, it should be included in the CLI by default. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 25):

In 2017, Heroku released [heroku-accounts](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts), an add-on to the toolbelt that lets one quickly switch accounts from the command line. Install it like this:

`heroku plugins:install heroku-accounts`

Then add an account ("work" in this case):

`heroku accounts:add work`

At this point, you'll need to provide the credentials you want associated with the "work" alias. Do the same for other accounts you have. Then switch between aliases like this:

`heroku accounts:set work`

(Sorry to zombie this question.)

Comment: The other answer was edited to be the same as this one. That's kinda cheesy.

Comment: Thank you very much `@IAmNan`! Now I can switch between multiple Heroku accounts!

Answer (score 11):

You can just run the login again from the command line:

```
heroku login
```

Enter your new email and password for the other account.

Comment: it's too troublesome if we need to login and logout multiple times (and also entering password again and again) just to switch account.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Might not be the most efficient answer, but it helped me out!

Comment: It's not working, the browser is just providing a button which says login. How can I login using a different account, after the "heroku login" command?

Comment: You have to create a new profile in your browser, log in to `heroku.com` and save the password, make sure the browser you're using is your default browser, make sure it's the only open browser window, and run `heroku login`. Now you can hit the "Login" button and log in to the CLI. I didn't wanna do all this, that's why I looked up "Multiple accounts in Heroku CLI" and came to this page. I think `@IAmNaN`'s answer could help me. I'm not sure...

Comment: Okay now I've tested `@IAmNan`'s answer. It works.