# Why is Heroku-accounts plug-in no longer working, and I'm no longer able switch between mulitple accounts in the CLI?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

For years I've used the [heroku-accounts](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts) plug-in to easily switch between different Heroku accounts when using the Heroku CLI toolbelt.

As of about a month ago, however, it has stopped working. Whenever I switch over to an account and try to do something, like log in to Rails console, I get the error **"Invalid credentials provided."** It then prompts me to type a letter, which opens a browser, which then prompts me to log in. In other words, I have to re-log in whenever I switch accounts, which is exactly what the plug in is supposed handle.

(heroku-accounts version = 1.1.7)

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts/issues/20) help?

Comment: Thanks @Chris, but couldn't resolve with their solution- see updated question

Comment: I tested and everything works for me as such. I would suggest two things. Uninstall `heroku-cli` remove `~/.config/heroku/` and `~/.local/share/heroku`. I have tested on `heroku/7.27.1 darwin-x64 node-v11.14.0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140375/heroku-toolbelt-switch-between-multiple-account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [thread](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts/issues/20#issuecomment-476369422) from @Chris, I played around with removing and re-adding the accounts until I finally got it working.